# Cyanogen's new c-apps dialer not working

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom-flashing, stock-android, phone-app

I recently installed a CyanogenMod bases rom called AICP one my phone and everything was working fine. Then a couple months later I found CyanogenMod's new c-apps. I decided to flash that. Now whenever I try to make/receive calls the new cyanogen dialer app crashes. Anybody know what's causing this?

Comment: @NVZ Yeah. Sorry, I posted it twice, I will delete this one